# Open submanifolds; why does $\mathcal{A}_U$ cover $U$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am currently reading Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, and have come across open submanifolds. Suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold, and that $U \subseteq M$ is an open set, and define $\mathcal{A}_U := \{\text{smooth charts } (V, \varphi) \text{ of } M \text{ such that } V \subseteq U\}$.

Lee says that it is easy to verify that $\mathcal{A}_U$ is a smooth atlas for $U$. I am stuck on showing that the charts in $\mathcal{A}_U$ cover $U$.

If I take an element $u \in U$, how do I assert the existence of a chart $(V, \varphi)$ in $\mathcal{A}_U$ such that $u \in V$? I am not even sure how to see that $\mathcal{A}_U$ is non-empty when $U$ is non-empty.

There are [other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214297/open-submanifolds) on this website about why $\mathcal{A}_U$ is a smooth atlas for $U$, but none that I have found address why $\mathcal{A}_U$ covers $U$. I feel that I am missing something simple here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern is valid since without additional assumptions, there is no reason for $\mathcal A_U$ to cover $U$. Consider the case of $U < \mathbb R^n$ a proper open subset where the atlas on $\mathbb R^n$ is $\mathcal A_{\mathbb R^n} = \{(\mathbb R^n, id)\}$. This is a completely valid atlas but its restriction to $\mathcal A_U$ is empty. What you're missing here is that different atlases can induce the same smooth strucure. Indeed, Lee discusses this on page 9 on his book where he gives two atlases on $\mathbb R^n$ - the one I listed above and $\{(B_1(x), id) : x \in \mathbb R^n\}$. These induce the same smooth structure. The definition of a smooth manifold (per Lee) is then a pair $(M, \mathcal A)$ where $M$ is a topological manifold and $\mathcal A$ is a *maximal* atlas. i.e. one not contained in any strictly larger smooth atlas. There is no loss of generality in working with maximal atlases, as Lee proves that every atlas in contained in a unique smooth atlas.

Now, given that $\mathcal A_M$ is maximal, we can prove that $\mathcal A_U$ covers $U$. Indeed, let $u \in U$. As $\mathcal A_M$ covers $M$ there is a $(W, \phi) \in \mathcal A_M$ such that $u \in W$. As $\mathcal A_M$ is maximal, the restriction $(W \cap U, \phi|_{W \cap U}) \in \mathcal A_M$ as well. Of course, this means that $(W \cap U, \phi|_{W \cap U}) \in \mathcal A_U$ so this atlas covers $U$.

Answer (score 0):

For any atlas $\{(U_i, \phi_i)\}$ of $M$, the restriction $\bigcap (U\cap U_i)$ covers $U$. The restriction of the map provides the atlas for the submanifold.

Comment: There is no guarantee that $U \cap U_i$ is a chart in $\mathcal A_U$ as defined by OP unless the atlas is taken to be maximal.